# Magento 2 add a attribute to customer register form not working

Tags: magento2

I have used MagePlaza social login module and trying to add a field for phone but somehow nothing is coming on popup. My template is caled on register page but not on register popup. Below is my layout code:-
In default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    !-- Fix Porto Popup login -->
    <referenceBlock name="form.additional.info">
        <block class="W3solver\Phone\Block\Customer" template="W3solver_Phone::Customer.phtml" name="customer_form_user_attributes" cacheable="false">
            <action method="setFormCode">
                <argument name="code" xsi:type="string">customer_account_edit</argument>
            </action>
            <action method="setEntityModelClass">
                <argument name="code" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Model\Customer</argument>
            </action>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

If anyone can help then it will be very greatful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try `form_additional_info` instead of `form.additional.info` because in extension `/Mageplaza/SocialLogin/view/frontend/templates/popup/form/create.phtml` here in line#157 `<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('form_additional_info'); ?>`this code is available.. so may be its works..

**UPDATE**

```
    <block class="W3solver\Phone\Block\Customer" template="W3solver_Phone::Customer.phtml" name="form.additional.info"  as="form.additional.info" cacheable="false">
        <action method="setFormCode">
            <argument name="code" xsi:type="string">customer_account_edit</argument>
        </action>
        <action method="setEntityModelClass">
            <argument name="code" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Model\Customer</argument>
        </action>
    </block>
```

Add this layout update inside the "popup.create" block in default.xml file..

Comment: Do you want me to make changes in mazeplaza module? My default.xml file path is W3solver\Phone\view\frontend\layout\default.xml

Comment: yes first try to add this code in mageplaza module then need to modify your default.xml

Comment: Will it be necessary to modify this module, is there any way we can do it from our custom module itself.